# nginx / mod_passenger on linode instance with oom messages - where to look next?

Tags: linux, nginx, oom

I am running an Ubuntu Server that is starting to have problems. It's very lightly used but am confused to why it is now having memory issues. I've included some of the output from syslog and free -m. What is this telling me exactly and what should I do next? Googling has provided some ambigous answers. It is only a 512MB instance and is set with 512MB of swap with a memory limit of 512 MB.

thx in advance for any help

```
Jan 14 06:25:15 curren rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.1" x-pid="2311" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Jan 14 06:25:16 curren CRON[3242]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: Pid: 2414, comm: mysqld Not tainted 3.6.5-x86_64-linode28 #1
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: Call Trace:
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810c5fd6>] dump_header+0x7d/0x1af
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810a2d96>] ? delayacct_end+0x74/0x7f
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff816ef5a2>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x1c
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff813ad18e>] ? ___ratelimit+0xe6/0x104
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810c6372>] oom_kill_process+0x66/0x30c
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810c6822>] out_of_memory+0x20a/0x263
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810ca096>] __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x403/0x4bc
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810ca299>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x14a/0x1ae
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff813ac0b0>] ? radix_tree_lookup+0x1e/0x54
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810f6391>] alloc_pages_current+0xc5/0xe6
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810c3afb>] __page_cache_alloc+0x87/0x94
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810c51d4>] filemap_fault+0x25a/0x341
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810e1b69>] __do_fault+0xa5/0x3a0
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810e2d03>] handle_pte_fault+0xdd/0x1b5
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff81004a4c>] ? xen_pmd_val+0x9/0xb
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff81004659>] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_pmd_val+0x11/0x1e
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff810e2f32>] handle_mm_fault+0x157/0x169
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff816f2947>] do_page_fault+0x364/0x389
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff81072fd1>] ? T.800+0x15/0x3b
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff81074011>] ? ktime_get_ts+0x44/0x93
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff81112067>] ? poll_select_copy_remaining+0xd2/0xf6
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff811122d1>] ? sys_select+0xa4/0xb9
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: [<ffffffff816efb65>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: Mem-Info:
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Jan 14 06:40:59 curren kernel: CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
```

here is result of free -m`

```
root@curren:/var/log# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           486        481          5          0          0          7
-/+ buffers/cache:        473         13
Swap:          511        507          4
root@curren:/var/log#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have run out of memory (and swap!).

Either tune your services to use less memory, or buy a VPS with more memory.

Comment: thx - is that based upon free -m analysis? Is there an easy way to see which pieces are configured to use specific amounts of memory

Comment: You can easily determine that with utilities such as `top`.

Comment: thx - I'll try to figure out but will prob be posting a second question